# How to write crossed north east and south east arrows?

Tags: symbols

A contravariant mappings f. I need the explanation of crossed arrows symbol

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What are you asking for exactly?

Comment: Please provide the code what you tried for till now, else provide an image which represent your requirement...

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a\makebox[0pt][l]{$\,\,\searrow$}\swarrow b$
\end{document}`?

Answer (score 8):

There are three possible options in the stix fonts:

`\toea` has no breaks in either arrow;

`\neovsearrow` has a gap in the southeast arrow;

`\seovnearrow` has a gap in the northeast arrow.

For details, see the comprehensive symbols list (`texdoc comprehensive`).

Example document:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  \verb|\toea| & $\toea$ \\
  \verb|\neovsearrow| & $\neovsearrow$ \\
  \verb|\seovnearrow| & $\seovnearrow$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}

$ \neovnwarrow \nwovnearrow $

\end{document}
```

[image]